# Getting row indices with multiple search patterns

Tags: matlab, indexing

In order to obtain indices (from a table of data) for rows containing a specific string or search pattern, I use:

```
rowID = find(data{:,{'ColumnA'}}==pattern(1));
```

Is there a way to perform a similar operation but with more than one pattern? e.g. in the following table:

```
Column A   Column B
   2           A
   2           A
   3           B
   4           B
   2           B
   2           B
```

Which can be quickly created using:

```
T = table();
T.Var1(1,1) = 2;
T.Var1(2,1) = 2;
T.Var1(3) = 3;
T.Var1(4) = 4;
T.Var1(5) = 2;
T.Var1(6) = 2;
T.Var2{1,1} = 'A';
T.Var2{2} = 'A';
T.Var2{3} = 'B';
T.Var2{4} = 'B';
T.Var2{5} = 'B';
T.Var2{6} = 'B';
```

I want to pull out row indices where ColumnA==2 and ColumnB=='A' i.e. [1 2].

Whilst trying dual indexing:

```
rowID = find(data{:,{'ColumnA'}}==2 & data{:,{'ColumnB'}}=='A');
```

It errors when attempting to match the string, with:

```
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Comment: you can combine logical indexing such as `find(data(:,1)==4 & data(:,2)==5000))`, but I am not sure if this is what you are looking for since you did not post a [mcve]

Comment: Updated with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Var1` in your example is a cell array of strings, you could use `strcmp`:

```
>> rowID = find(T{:,{'Var1'}}==2 &  strcmp(T{:,{'Var2'}},'A')

rowID =

 1
 2
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I was not aware you could combine logical indexing.